# Firebase Auth - How Long is Recent Login

Tags: javascript, firebase, authentication, web, firebase-authentication

I have a profile tab in which a user can press edit and edit their profile. I only want to require their password if I have to. So wanted to know how long is how many milliseconds of a user being signed in makes it not a recent login, in which firebase will throw the error `"auth/requires-recent-login"` when editing a users account? `new Date(Date.parse(firebase.auth().currentUser.metadata.lastSignInTime)).getTime()` Will give me an approximation of the last login (in milliseconds within 2000 milliseconds). I just want to know at what time should I ask the user to reauthenticate?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Firebase Authentication sign-ins are permanent There is no specific time-out on the authentication of a user, so you should not ask them to re-authenticate based on the expired time.

The only you should ask the user to re-authenticate is when you perform an action in the code that requires recent authentication and it fails with a `auth/requires-recent-login` error code.

For example, this is how [FirebaseUI detects the error upon user deletion](https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web/blob/49de7f69577e543451e41843854c29055974d275/demo/public/app.js#L161):

> ```
>  firebase.auth().currentUser.delete().catch(function(error) {
>   if (error.code == 'auth/requires-recent-login') {
>     // The user's credential is too old. She needs to sign in again.
> ```

Comment: When should I ask them to reauthenticate? When you try to change their password without a "Recent login" firebase throws the error `"auth/requires-recent-login"`

Comment: @frank-van-puffelen _"you should not ask them to re-authenticate based on the expired time"_
Why not? The fact that the server throws this error hints that Firebase **does** have a way of deciding what "recent" is. Is exposing the timeout value considered a security vulnerability?

Comment: Seems unnecessary making 2 round-trips to the server.

Comment: @ShyAgam You should instead capture that error ('auth/requires-recent-login') when occurs, not by an expiration time. So you can redirect to log in and then back (with/without prefilled data). By expiration time, imagine user stays there waiting for hours: you will be ending by asking credentials each x minutes (instead of only one time, when needed).

Answer (score 0):

`firebase.auth().currentUser.metadata`

If you type `firebase.auth()` in your browsers console and expand/view the resulting object you will find a `metadata` property under `currentUser` which contains the following fields. Note I added the dashes to hide the data in my output.

```
  metadata:
    Ia {a: "15---------00", 
    b: "15--------00", 
    lastSignInTime: "Wed, 13 Jun 2018 10:01:46 GMT", 
    creationTime: "Thu, 19 Apr 2018 18:48:09 GMT"}
```

Comment: That isn't even my question. I am asking how many milliseconds of a sign in makes not a recent login. Not I how to get the time a user has been signed in for. To clarify you need to a "Recent Login" to change your password otherwise, firebase throws the error "auth/requires-recent-login."